# How to write bresenham algorithms in c#?

Tags: c#, graph-algorithm

I wrote like this but it works only in 50% cases. Can someone tell what's wrong?

```
public void Bresenham(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,Color c)
        {            
            double dx = x2 - x1;
            double dy = y2 - y1;
            double d = 2*dy-dx; //aux variable
            double p1 = 2 * dy ;
            double p2 = 2 * (dy - dx);
            int x = x1;
            int y = y1;
            int xend;
            c = kolor;
            if (x1 > x2)
            {
                x = x2;
                y = y2;
                xend = x1;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x1;
                y = y1;
                xend = x2;
            }
            bitmapa.SetPixel(x, y,c);
            try
            {
                while (x < xend)
                {
                    x++;
                    if (d < 0)
                    {
                        d += p1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d += p2;
                        y += 1;
                    }
                    bitmapa.SetPixel(x, y, c);
                }
            }
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Note: "zmienna pomocnicza" = "auxiliary variable".

Comment: Please edit to make comments English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first shot, you are missing a case when other coordinate should be handled like now your are handling Y.  You now handle the case when DY < DX, you should also handle case when DX < DY, i.e. slope of the line is different.

To understand what I'm saying, look `steep` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

And actually, your algorithm will work only in 1/4 cases.

Comment: @Vamana: look at the page in the link and search for the 'steep' variable.